# Why is max(Date) giving 2 different outputs in R?

Tags: r, date, max, sqldf

I have 2 datasets :-
Equity and ReturnEXP. Both go to 2018-03-31.
I tried max(Date) in both and in the former, i am getting the correct date 2018-03-31 while in the latter iam getting 1997-04-30
I checked both classes, both are "Date".
Here are the codes i tried:-

```
 ReturnEXP[ReturnEXP$Date == max(ReturnEXP$Date),]
 sqldf("select * from ReturnEXP where Date = (select Max(Date) from ReturnEXP)")
```

ReturnEXP

```
 structure(list(Date = structure(c("-25537", "-25509", "-25478", 
"-25448", "-25417", "-25387"), class = "Date")), .Names = "Date", row.names 
= c(NA,6L), class = "data.frame")

 > dput(tail(ReturnEXP$Date))
 structure(c("17470", "17500", "17531", "17562", "17590", "17621"
 ), class = "Date")
```

Equity

```
 structure(list(Date = structure(c(16921, 16952, 16982, 17013, 
17044, 17074), class = "Date")), .Names = "Date", row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

In both cases iam getting the same result 1997
Can anyone tell me what to do to get 2018?
Thanks

Comment: You need to show us a couple of rows of data. Use `dput()`. so we can reproduce this.

Comment: Please, don't put code in comments it is unreadable. Instead, put the output of `dput(head(ReturnEXP))` in your question. If it has many columns or factor columns, do a relevant subset, like `dput(head(ReturnEXP["Date"]))`.

Comment: sorry, just did it

Comment: Your data looks fine (though your `ReturnEXP` starts very early with 1900-01-31). Are you sure the result is wrong? Maybe `ReturnEXP` doesn't go as far forward in time as you think. How do you know that it goes to 2018?

Comment: Yes it does.  Is there any function like head which shows the bottom ? i can put that in my question details

Comment: maybe it is the early date which is the problem? Maybe i do max(ReturEXP[ReturnEXP$Date>"Some magic date","Date"]) (essentially change the start date)? But i don't know the correct start date from where R starts measuring stuff

Comment: `tail` does the opposite of `head`.

Comment: Rs 'origin date' starts 1970-01-01. In your ReturnEXP you have negative dates so it will subtract the days from 1970-01-01 to give you dates before 1970. I think you have to know your origin start date.

Comment: the origin date is correct....i can't change it to 1970...is there some workaround?

Comment: If you show us your original input we can try to help. If you input a numeric to `as.Date` you can specify whatever origin you want.

Comment: i added the tail...my question is :- what is the logic of getting 1997 aka 9981 in numeric terms. I understand that the -25,537 is the number of days between 01-01-1970 and 01-31-1900, but why is this giving a random number as the max?

Comment: Gregor, what else do you need? Thanks

Comment: The `dput` output looks bizarre.  It has character data in it but Date objects are supposed to have numeric data underlying them.  Maybe `ReturnEXP2 <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(as.numeric(ReturnEXP$Date), "1970-01-01"))` can fix it but better would be to figure out how it came about.